# How do I to find values in a nested JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to find a value in a nested JSON using PHP. I've done a `print_r()` of it and get:

```
Array
(
    [types] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Running
                    [arabicName] => Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø§Ø±ÙŠ
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Entertainment
                                    [arabicName] => ØªØ³Ù„ÙŠØ©
                                    [programs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 375
                                                    [name] => Saalo Marteh
                                                    [arabicName] => 
                                                    [image] => http://plus.mtv.com.lb/Chrome/KPanel/Pictures/Programs/151120100928327.jpg
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 491
                                                    [name] => Celebrity Duets
                                                    [arabicName] => 
                                                    [image] => http://plus.mtv.com.lb/Chrome/KPanel/Pictures/Programs/151108084429774.jpg
                                                )
```

I'm trying to get the value for `name` and `id` under the entertainment header.
I've tried the following but no luck:

```
echo $json['types']['categories'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: `echo $json['types'][0]['categories'][0]['name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($json['types'][0]['categories'][0]['programs'] as $value) {
    echo $value['id'] . ' ' . $value['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!!